# i want to select dependent values from drop down using IF condition in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to select values from drop down that are interdependent to each other when I select dropdown1 - its gives some specific value and when i select drop down2  it gives some different values so using if condition to check the if(dropdown1 == x)
{ select y }
else 
{ select A }

```
public class SelectingRadioButtons {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
            "C:\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://careerendeavour.com/admission-form/registration-form.php");
        Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='center']")));
        dropdown.selectByIndex(2);

        Select subcourse = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='course']")));
        subcourse.selectByValue("Regular Course");

        if (subcourse.equals("Regular Course")) {
            Select dropdown1 =  new Select(driver.findElement(
                By.xpath(".//*[@id='coursetp']")));
            dropdown1.selectByValue("GATE");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your test case should know if it's selecting a regular course or not. Generally speaking, you should avoid `if` statements like that in your test logic to make your code easier to maintain, more readable, and less flaky. It also might be worth resetting up your project using a **unit test framework** like **junit** earlier rather than later so you're not running tests through a `main` method.

Comment: That being said, you can get the element of the course you're going to click on, and check it's value. `if(subCourseElement.getAttribute("value").equals("Regular Course")`

Comment: So where are you stuck? Considering `subcoarse` as an instance of `Select` class it will work on select options only. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of dropdown as follows,

```
String selectedcourse = subcourse.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```

Then you compare like,

```
if (selectedcourse.equals("Regular Course")) { 
    Select dropdown1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='coursetp']"))); 
    dropdown1.selectByValue("GATE");
}
```